# Get DB Values And Store 2D Array And Display

Tags: java, jtable, resultset

1) i already get  database values from database but i i want store that data to 2D array and display them.

2)actually i want store that data to jTbale because i want to add my table to checkbox column to select multiple row. i use this 
tblEmployee.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
but the problem is wheni use that it display Database table it Repalce my check box coloumn

3)my idea is get that result set values and store into 2d array and then apply that data to my tblEmployee

[image: this is my table]

Comment: You probably might want to show some effort by doing at least 2 things: 1) format your question and correct the spelling and 2) show some code (and 3) you might want to provide some examples to make your question easier to understand, e.g. what check box column are you talking about?).

Comment: corrected.i added picture

Comment: Just that picture doesn't help very much without a more detailed example, e.g. some code.